# What Causes G1 GC Suspension Time when No Full GC is Reported?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

I am using monitoring tool - DynaTrace and I don't see Full GC occurring however there is a GC Suspension time getting reported. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Dynatrace reports time that the application is doing other things than executing your code as *suspension time*. The typical example is that the application is paused to perform garbage collection.

G1 does different kinds of collections, both minor and major (also known as full collections). Both collection types pauses the application for some time.

Even if you do not see any full collections reported, you will see suspension time due to *minor* collections.